# Is it possible to give priorities to audio input sources while recording in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, audio, record

I'm using Audio Sessions and Queues. I will explain the scenario:
1. iPad has USB audio interface connected using USB camera kit accessory.
2. App starts recording the audio.
3. User plugs in the headphone.
4. Audio Session automatically starts getting audio from headphone's mic.

Question:
Is there any way to keep getting the audio from the USB connection ? No matter the headphone is connected ?